# Item limit for list box control in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I am using a Listbox control under ScrollViewer control. I have made binding of items of Listbox control.

```
<ScrollViewer 
    Name="AgreementsSV" >
    <ListBox 
        x:Name="MyAgr"  
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyAgreementList}"
        SelectedIndex="-1" >
        <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand 
                x:Name="AgreementTapCommand"
                Command="{Binding NavigateToDetailsCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyAgr}"/>
            </Custom:EventTrigger>
        </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

from back-end i am fetching 50 items at a time and adding them to the list.
this works fine till i reach 600 items in the list. after that application crashed. i didn't find any exception.

So i want to make sure is there any item limit to Listbox control or ScrollViewer? is there any alternative option for List box control?

Code for getting data for listbox.

```
TotalRecordsExists = responseJson.total;
foreach (Agreement item in responseJson.rows)
{
    MyAgreementList.Add(item);
    TotalRecordsFetched++;
}
if (TotalRecordsFetched < TotalRecordsExists)
{
    PageNumber++;
    GetMyAgreements();
}
```

Comment: Why have you added your listbox inside a scrollviewer? The listbox has a scrollviewer of itself. I suggest you remove the scrollviewer and try again.

Comment: Also please set some breakpoints in the function where you are fetching data from the backend. It is possible that the backend is returning you some error after 600 items. Please verify that everything is running properly till you are adding items to the collection and that the crash is happening only after that.

Comment: Why have you set the ItemsPanel to StackPanel?

Comment: thanks rajeev for your quick response, i have tryed fetching 1000 items in one go. first 1000 items comes perfectly and in second iteration applications crashes, without hitting any break point

Comment: Are you fetching the next set of items when you reach the bottom of the list? Could you please post some code for those functions as well? Did you try removing the scrollviewer?

Comment: Thank you rajeev removal of scrollviewer works for me. thank you so much. but still i am not digesting the thing that why it was not working with scroll viewer.

Comment: i have updated the question with the logic for getting my agreements from service. simply i was using webclient to get data from service. and after getting first set of data i check with total count and again get next set of agreements.

Comment: Since removing the scrollviewer solved the issue, we can assume there was no problem with your data parsing. Please upload your entire project somewhere so that I can have a look at it. Also let me post the scrollviewer thing as an answer so that you can mark it.

Comment: @RajeevBhatia: thanks man, can u please tell me how to clear cache of webbrowser control. i have used webbrowser control to login to MSFT but logout is not working for me

Comment: Can you start a different question for that with the source code? Cannot understand your exact problem without the source!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add the ListBox inside a ScrollViewer. The ListBox ContentControl has it's own inbuilt scrollviewer which should work fine.

Try out this code:-

```
            <ListBox 
                x:Name="MyAgr"  
                ItemsSource="{Binding MyAgreementList}"
                SelectedIndex="-1" >
                <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                        <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand 
                        x:Name="AgreementTapCommand"
                        Command="{Binding NavigateToDetailsCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyAgr}"/>
                    </Custom:EventTrigger>
                </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Also I don't see the need for the StackPanel ItemsPanel in there.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are encountering out of memory in your app. Instead of using stackpanel, use virtualizedstackpanel which does data virtualization by default. Also you can try using the LongListSelector instead of the ListBox.